# Boolean Function c# not all code return a value

Tags: c#, function, boolean, func

What am I doing wrong here?

At the end of the function, I'm returning the result.

```
 public bool  isStipends() 
    {
        try
        {
            bool result = true;
            if (tbstipend.Text == "" || tbstipend.Text == "Required")
            {
                tbstipend.Text = "Required";
                tbstipend.BackColor = Color.Red;
                tbstipend.ForeColor = Color.White;
                result =  false;
            }
            else if  (tbstipendperperiod.Text == "" || tbstipendperperiod.Text == "Required")
            {
                tbstipendperperiod.Text = "Required";
                tbstipendperperiod.BackColor = Color.Red;
                tbstipendperperiod.ForeColor = Color.White;
                result = false;
            }

            else  if (tbstipendsperinterval.Text == "" || tbstipendsperinterval.Text == "Required")
            {
                tbstipendsperinterval.Text = "Required";
                tbstipendsperinterval.BackColor = Color.Red;
                tbstipendsperinterval.ForeColor = Color.White;
                result = false;
            }

            else if (tbstipendrate.Text == "" || tbstipendrate.Text == "Required")
            {
                tbstipendrate.Text = "Required";
                tbstipendrate.BackColor = Color.Red;
                tbstipendrate.ForeColor = Color.White;
                result =  false;
            }
            else
            {
                return result;
            }

        }
        catch 
          {
             return false;
          }
    }
```

In the code behind of the button, I call:

```
 private void btnupdatestipends_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (isStipends() == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("TEST");
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

However, it gives me an error on the function itself.

> Error 3   'AddressBookMaint.Form1.isStipends()': not all code paths return a value    C:\Win\AddressBookMaint\AddressBookMaint\Form1.cs   5040    22  AddressBookMaint

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: What will be returned in case of an exception?

Comment: You are not returning anything in catch

Comment: Along with not returning anything if an exception is thrown, you are also not returning anything if any of `if/else if`s are true.

Comment: I don't really need to return anything in the catch {}

Comment: @user1426542 but you do. All paths must return a value.

Comment: @user1426542: Then what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Move the 'return result' outside of else block.

Comment: And stop swallowing exceptions, that's a very bad habit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to return something in your catch:

```
public bool Method() {
    try {
        return true;
    }
    catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or just return a single value at the bottom:

```
public bool Method() {
    bool result = false;
    try {
        ...
        result = true;
    }
    catch {}

    return result;
}
```

Comment: and what about all the `if` blocks? they don't return a value either?

Comment: @clcto - You could just `return false` in your ifs if you're looking at my first example. If you're looking at the second example, you would just set `result = false` and then let it be returned at the end of the method.

Comment: I added a return false after the catch statement and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi - Fixed the return type. Should compile now but the example is really just an example of how to return a value from a method with a try/catch.

Comment: Yes but you were returning from the `try` block and also after that. So two returns in a function wont work.

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi - That's incorrect. You can return from a function more than once.

Comment: You can only return once buddy. However you can use as many returns you want but only one of them will return. You were returning two values from your code... that's why it would not compile...

Comment: My "You can return from a function more than once." meant the same as your "you can use as many returns you want". I'm confused by what you mean. My example has always complied (at least until I changed the return type to bool from void.)

Answer (score 4):

### Error 1

You are only returning if none of the if's are true since the `return` is in the last `else` clause.

#### Solution

Break out the `return` from the last `else` and place it in the `try` block *(or even outside of the try/catch and you will solve error 2 as well)*.

### Error 2

You will only return if there are no exceptions since you have the `return` at the end of the `try` block and no `return` in the `catch` block.

#### Solution

Add a `return` in the `catch` block and the code will compile.

### Here's a working version of your code

```
public bool  isStipends() 
{
    bool result = true;
    try
    {
        
        if (tbstipend.Text == "" || tbstipend.Text == "Required")
        {
            tbstipend.Text = "Required";
            tbstipend.BackColor = Color.Red;
            tbstipend.ForeColor = Color.White;
            result =  false;
        }
        else if  (tbstipendperperiod.Text == "" || tbstipendperperiod.Text == "Required")
        {
            tbstipendperperiod.Text = "Required";
            tbstipendperperiod.BackColor = Color.Red;
            tbstipendperperiod.ForeColor = Color.White;
            result = false;
        }

        else  if (tbstipendsperinterval.Text == "" || tbstipendsperinterval.Text == "Required")
        {
            tbstipendsperinterval.Text = "Required";
            tbstipendsperinterval.BackColor = Color.Red;
            tbstipendsperinterval.ForeColor = Color.White;
            result = false;
        }

        else if (tbstipendrate.Text == "" || tbstipendrate.Text == "Required")
        {
            tbstipendrate.Text = "Required";
            tbstipendrate.BackColor = Color.Red;
            tbstipendrate.ForeColor = Color.White;
            result =  false;
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
        result = false;
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I added return false; to catch block, still the same error.

Comment: @clcto added some about the if.

Comment: @user1426542 What if this statement is true `if (tbstipend.Text == "" || tbstipend.Text == "Required")`? Then no `return ...;` statement is executed, which explains the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code only specifies the return in the final `else` block. In all your other code paths, including the catch block, you haven't specified any return value. You can drop that final `else` block and add a return value at the end of your function, like this:

```
public bool  isStipends() 
{
    bool result = true;
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch
    {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

However, catching all exceptions like this is very bad practice, and you *certainly* don't need to do it inside every function. You should only catch the exceptions you can meaningfully handle and allow the rest to bubble up. Set a global unhandled exception if need be to gracefully bail out of your application.

See [Best Practices for Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

replace your method isStipends by this on:

```
public bool  isStipends() 
{
    try
    {
        bool result = true;
        if (tbstipend.Text == "" || tbstipend.Text == "Required")
        {
            tbstipend.Text = "Required";
            tbstipend.BackColor = Color.Red;
            tbstipend.ForeColor = Color.White;
            result =  false;
        }
        else if  (tbstipendperperiod.Text == "" || tbstipendperperiod.Text == "Required")
        {
            tbstipendperperiod.Text = "Required";
            tbstipendperperiod.BackColor = Color.Red;
            tbstipendperperiod.ForeColor = Color.White;
            result = false;
        }

        else  if (tbstipendsperinterval.Text == "" || tbstipendsperinterval.Text == "Required")
        {
            tbstipendsperinterval.Text = "Required";
            tbstipendsperinterval.BackColor = Color.Red;
            tbstipendsperinterval.ForeColor = Color.White;
            result = false;
        }

        else if (tbstipendrate.Text == "" || tbstipendrate.Text == "Required")
        {
            tbstipendrate.Text = "Required";
            tbstipendrate.BackColor = Color.Red;
            tbstipendrate.ForeColor = Color.White;
            result =  false;
        }
        return result;

    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: Just "replace your code with this" isn't a good answer. No explanation about why the error is occurring. And besides, your code won't compile.

Comment: This still has the exact same problem as the original question. Can't just return result in the try.

Comment: the problem is not in the try catch block. it is in the if else. when we run the application if one of the if or the if else are true so there is nothing to return and this why we should add the instruction return result after the block if else

Comment: @Lamourou - But what happens if an exception is thrown and the catch block is executed? There's nothing to return in or after the catch block so therefore not all code paths return a value. Your code, as is, will not compile.

Comment: add catch { return false; }

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that there are ways that do not return any value, if there is a mistake your catch instruction will returns nothing.

returns some value in your instruction catch.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything anywhere in your code... except for your last `else` statement. To compile all paths should return a `bool` value for your method. You should return a value in every `if` or `if else` and `else` statement, and in your catch block.

This will work:

```
public bool  isStipends() 
{
    try
    {
        bool result = true;
        if (tbstipend.Text == "" || tbstipend.Text == "Required")
        {
            tbstipend.Text = "Required";
            tbstipend.BackColor = Color.Red;
            tbstipend.ForeColor = Color.White;
            result =  false;
        }
        else if  (tbstipendperperiod.Text == "" || tbstipendperperiod.Text == "Required")
        {
            tbstipendperperiod.Text = "Required";
            tbstipendperperiod.BackColor = Color.Red;
            tbstipendperperiod.ForeColor = Color.White;
            result = false;
        }
        else  if (tbstipendsperinterval.Text == "" || tbstipendsperinterval.Text == "Required")
        {
            tbstipendsperinterval.Text = "Required";
            tbstipendsperinterval.BackColor = Color.Red;
            tbstipendsperinterval.ForeColor = Color.White;
            result = false;
        }
        else if (tbstipendrate.Text == "" || tbstipendrate.Text == "Required")
        {
            tbstipendrate.Text = "Required";
            tbstipendrate.BackColor = Color.Red;
            tbstipendrate.ForeColor = Color.White;
            result =  false;
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
        return false;
    }
    return result;
}
```